# Xcode won't recognize my jailbroken iPhone even though I have a provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, xcode

I have a paid developer account with Apple and my phone has a valid provisioning profile installed on it.

I jailbroke my iPhone because in iOS 7 there is no 3G toggle switch; without the toggle my batteries drain in ~6 hours.

I've tried to launch an app under development in Xcode on the phone but Xcode crashes while checking my iPhone.

How can I make this work?

Comment: When you say "but it crashes" what is the "it" you are referring to? The OS on the phone or Xcode?

Comment: Xcode, I mean Xcode. I crush while checking bundle identifier on the phone I think